# How can i get the URL params in back-end if nodeJs

Tags: typescript

I want to read querystring parameters `email`, `job` and `source` from this URL...

> https://teste.com/?email=leonardocanario007%40gmail.com&job=xxxxxSvTfuoto&source=xxxxx

...and use them inside my service class...

```
@Injectable()
export class TesteService{

    constructor(){}

    async verifiedingData(urlSite: URL){
        
        const url = new URLSearchParams(urlSite.search)
        const emailParam = url.get("email");
        console.log(emailParam);

    }

}
```

...and in the controller:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard())
@Controller('Test')
export class test{

    constructor(private readonly testeService: TesteService){}

    @Get('loginTest')
    @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
    async redirect(){
        return await this.testeService.verifiedingData(url);
    }
}
```

I put the URL manually but I can't because the VS Code comments the code and after I have taken these parameters from the URL, I need to redirect to another URL.

How do I access the querystring parameter values?

Comment: which framework is it that you are using ?

Comment: NestJs i'm using

Comment: Do you intend to read query parameters of `current request` ?

Answer (score 0):

With some adjustments so that I can run it locally....

**test.service.ts**

```ts
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

export interface VerificationInput {
    readonly email: string;
    readonly job: string;
    readonly source: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

    constructor() { }

    async verifiedingData(verificationInput: VerificationInput) {

        // const url = new URLSearchParams(urlSite.search)
        // const emailParam = url.get("email");
        return {
            "inputEmail": verificationInput.email,
            "inputJob": verificationInput.job,
            "inputsource": verificationInput.source
        };
    }
}
```

**test.controller.ts**

```ts
import { Controller, UseGuards, Get, UsePipes, ValidationPipe, Query } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TestService } from "./test.service";

// @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
@Controller('Test')
export class TestController {

    constructor(private readonly testService: TestService) { }

    @Get('loginTest')
    @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
    async redirect(
        @Query('email') email,  // <---- Inject 'email' query param
        @Query('job') job,      // <---- Inject 'job' query param
        @Query('source') source // <---- Inject 'source' query param
    ) {
        return await this.testService.verifiedingData({ email, job, source });
    }
}
```

---

### ***Assumptions***

> The author wants to read query params from the context of the `current request`

---

---

***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***